# Issue in EF, mapping fragment,no default value and is not nullable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I am developing MVC 3 Applicaiton.

I have Model first approch.

I have Company Entity(Abstract).
Lead and Customer is inherited from the company entity.

When I tried to validate the model, Its gives an errror.

> Error 41  Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   70:Column Companies.Status in table Companies must be mapped: It has
>   no default value and is not nullable.

Here is the mapping of tables.

[image]

And Here is the EDMX code in HTML View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="Model1.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator">
    <EntityContainer Name="Model1StoreContainer">

        <EntitySet Name="Companies" EntityType="Model1.Store.Companies" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />

    </EntityContainer>

    <EntityType Name="Companies">
        <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Status" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="__Disc__" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="Max" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
</Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" Namespace="Model1" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
        <EntityContainer Name="Model1Container" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="Companies" EntityType="Model1.Company" />
          </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Company" Abstract="true">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="Id" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Lead" BaseType="Model1.Company" >
          <Property Type="String" Name="Status" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
    <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs">
    <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="Model1StoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="Model1Container">
        <EntitySetMapping Name="Companies">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(Model1.Company)">
                <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Companies">
                    <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                    <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
                    <Condition ColumnName="__Disc__" Value="Company" />
                </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Model1.Lead">
                <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Companies">
                    <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                    <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
                    <ScalarProperty Name="Status" ColumnName="Status" />
                    <Condition ColumnName="__Disc__" Value="Lead" />
                </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
        </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
</Mapping></edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
    <edmx:Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </edmx:Connection>
    <edmx:Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="True" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="DatabaseGenerationWorkflow" Value="$(VSEFTools)\DBGen\Generate T-SQL Via T4 (TPH).xaml" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </edmx:Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram Name="Model1" >
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model1.Company" Width="1.5" PointX="2.375" PointY="0.875" Height="1.2636116536458335" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model1.Lead" Width="1.5" PointX="3.375" PointY="2.625" Height="1.0992643229166665" />
        <InheritanceConnector EntityType="Model1.Lead" >
          <ConnectorPoint PointX="3.125" PointY="2.1386116536458335" />
          <ConnectorPoint PointX="3.125" PointY="2.325" />
          <ConnectorPoint PointX="4.125" PointY="2.325" />
          <ConnectorPoint PointX="4.125" PointY="2.625" />
        </InheritanceConnector>
        </Diagram>
    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Whats is the issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the DefaultValue attribute on the SSDL Status property. It would look like this (I used the empty string):

```
<Property Name="Status" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" DefaultValue=""/>
```

Since the base entity is abstract you won't be able to create entities of this type so this DefaultValue will not really be used but it should make EF stop complaining.

Comment: Can this also be done in the UI/Designer somewhere?

Comment: While this solved the problem in the OP for me, upon running the code I'm finding that I can't insert a record into the table, as EF tries to put null into the column despite the DefaultValue.  I've also tried setting a Default Value in the designer, and the problem remains.  Does anyone know of a solution or is it just mandatory that all columns be marked nullable?

Answer (score 0):

In your storage model, the Companies.Status column doesn't allow null values.

Since all entities that inherit from Company except the Lead entity will not have the Status property set, you need to either allow null in the Companies.Status column or set a default value to use for the other entities.